# Serialization of data for protocol implementation

Tags: serialization, protocols, code-generation

I am to implement a communication protocol. The data structures used in the protocol are defined as bytes per field in each message

```
bytes 1-2         -> stx bytes
bytes 3           -> mesg type
bytes 4-5         -> size of pay load
bytes 6-...       -> pay load bytes (unsigned bytes)
bytes ... - ...+1 -> checksum from byte 3 - ...
bytes ...+2       -> end byte
```

the example above is variable pay load size, but some Messages are also fixed size.

I have checked a serialization library, namely "protocol buffers" for this purpose but I concluded that protobuf is not complainant as the variant types used change the data serialized.
similar libraries exist but I am not sure if they can be used fir this purpose (flat buffers, cap'n proto).

So, is there a framework to define the interface structures and generate appropriate code (*data structures + parser + serializer, with support for multiple languages if possible*) for the defined interface?

Or what is the best approach you would suggest for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining the messages used in a protocol by defining what each byte means is, well, old fashioned. Having said that, an awful lot of current protocols are defined that way.

If you can, it's better to start off with a schema for the protocol (e.g. a `.proto` file for Google Protocol Buffers, or an `.asn` file for ASN.1, etc. There's many to choose from), defining the messages you want to exchange, and then use your chosen serialisation technologies tools (e.g. `protoc` for G.P.B, `asn1c` for ASN.1, etc) to generate code.

That schema would be defining the content of the "payload" bytes in your example, and you'd leave it up to GPB or whatever to work out how to convey message type, size and length for you. Different serialisation technologies have different capabilities in this regard. In GPB you'd use a `oneof` structure to incorporate all the different types of content you want to send into a single structure, but GPB doesn't demarcate between different messages on the wire (you have to add that yourself, perhaps by sending messages using ZeroMQ). Several ASN.1 wire formats do demarcate between different messages, saving you the bother (useful on a raw stream connection). XML is also demarcated. I don't think Cap'n Proto does demarcation.

If you're stuck with the protocol as defined byte-by-byte, exactly as you've shown, it's going to be difficult to find a serialisation technology that usefully matches. You'd likely be condemned to writing all the code yourself.

Comment: Yes I guess you are right I am to write all the code by myself instead of using some serialization tool. I will use GSL (https://github.com/imatix/gsl) and try to generate as much as I could. Thank you anyhow. :)